# Utorrent No Longer Storing Files In Subdirectories

Tags: utorrent

My Windows 10 computer has suddenly stopped storing utorrent downloading files in their subdirectories and is now storing everything as a jumble of files in my chosen download directory. This just started happening in the last couple of days. Any idea how to get the files to start storing in the subdirectories specified in each torrent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

μTorrent has a checkbox on the "add torrent" screen that allows you to create a new folder for the torrent. I believe its state persists over restarts.

Make sure that you have checked this box when adding a new torrent.

I'll edit this answer when I get home to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Options > Preferences > Directories > uncheck "Move completed torrents to..."

Comment: Welcome to Super User please refer this link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer will help you to improve you post. I do believe that your post needs more illustrations.